# XML to Datamodel synchronisation strategies

Tags: algorithm, synchronization

I have an XML data source, which I'm loading / refreshing.

I'm populating a data model from this source and would like to manage synchronisation issues

e.g. being able to notify the GUI/User when items have been removed, had their values increased / decreased, changed... etc.

I'm wondering if there is a *standard* way of doing this?

It seems to me that the model / data objects will need to individually implement update / change flagging code.

I'll be doing what I can to reduce dependency as much as possible, but I'm looking for ideas, and I'm assuming this is ground that has been well trodden before.

Answer (score 0):

you can right-click import XML into Access, and it will split it into a bunch of different tables.

I've done this on a commercial scale before.. for tons and tons of SQL and XML.. it worked allright.